# Locating ids with forward slashes

Tags: javascript, selenium, css-selectors, webdriver, webdriver-io

I have the following button:

```
<button id="Organisation/user" class="button-2xhG8" data-reactid=".0.2:$organization.0.0.2:$1/47">org</button>
```

And I am trying to click on it using:

```
browser.waitForExist("#Organisation/user",10000)
browser.click("#Organisation/user")
```

to no avail. The following does work though:

```
 browser.waitForExist(".button-2xhG8",10000)
 browser.click(".button-2xhG8")
```

and I can click on other buttons without don't user forward slashes in their ids. How do I locate the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to double-escape special characters in attributes

```
browser.waitForExist("#Organisation\\/user",10000)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select your button like `button[id='Organisation/user']`.